# Subtracting each elements of a row vector , size (1 x n) from a matrix of size (m x n)

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices of big sizes, which are something similar to the following matrices.

m; with size 1000 by 10
n; with size 1 by 10.

I would like to subtract each element of n from all elements of m to get ten different matrices, each has size of 1000 by 10.

I started as follows

```
clc;clear;
nrow = 10000;
ncol = 10;
t = length(n)
for i = 1:nrow;
    for j = 1:ncol;
       for t = 1:length(n);
       m1(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(1); 
       m2(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(2);
       m3(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(3);
       m4(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(4);
       m5(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(5);
       m6(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(6);
       m7(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(7);
       m8(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(8);
       m9(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(9);
       m10(i,j) = m(i,j)-n(10);
       end
    end
end
```

can any one help me how can I do it without writing the ten equations inside the loop? Or can suggest me any convenient way especially when the two matrices has many columns.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just do this:

```
m01 = m - n(1);
...
m10 = m - n(10);
```

What do you need the loop for?

Even better:

```
N = length(n);
m2 = cell(N, 1);
for k = 1:N
  m2{k} = m - n(k);
end
```

Comment: Again, I would like to count the number of negative elements in each column of the resulting matrices. How Can I do this inside the loop that you gave me before?

Answer (score 2):

Here we go loopless:

```
nrow = 10000;
ncol = 10;

%example data
m = ones(nrow,ncol);
n = 1:ncol;

M = repmat(m,1,1,ncol);
N = permute( repmat(n,nrow,1,ncol) , [1 3 2] );
result = bsxfun(@minus, M, N );
%or just
result = M-N;
```

> Elapsed time is 0.018499 seconds.

or as recommended by Luis Mendo:

```
M = repmat(m,1,1,ncol);
result = bsxfun(@minus, m, permute(n, [1 3 2]) );
```

> Elapsed time is 0.000094 seconds.

please make sure that your input vectors have the same orientation like in my example, otherwise you could get in trouble. You should be able to obtain that by transposements or you have to modify this line:

```
permute( repmat(n,nrow,1,ncol) , [1 3 2] )
```

according to your needs.

---

You mentioned in a comment that you want to count the negative elements in each of the obtained columns:

```
A = result;                 %backup results 
A(A > 0) = 0;               %set non-negative elements to zero
D = sum( logical(A),3 );
```

which will return the desired **10000x10** matrix with quantities of negative elements. (Please verify it, I may got a little confused with the dimensions ;))

Comment: `bsxfun` much better than `for`. But you don't need the two `repmat`! In fact, `bsxfun` is intended to replace `repmat` more efficiently. Just use `result = bsxfun(@minus, m, permute(n, [1 3 2]) );`

Comment: Welcome! Note that the code then reduces to just that single line (no need for `M`) And if you keep the `repmat` version, `bsxfun` is not needed: just use `result = M-N;` (as `M` and `N` are already of matching sizes)

Answer (score 1):

Create the three dimensional result matrix. Store your results, for example, in third dimension.

```
clc;clear;
nrow = 10000;
ncol = 10;
N = length(n);
resultMatrix = zeros(nrow, ncol, N);
neg = zeros(ncol, N); % amount of negative values
for j = 1:ncol
    for i = 1:nrow
        for t = 1:N
            resultMatrix(i,j,t) = m(i,j) - n(t);
        end
    end
    for t = 1:N
        neg(j,t) = length( find(resultMatrix(:,j,t) < 0) );
    end
end
```

Comment: Again, I would like to count the number of negative elements in each column of the resulting matrices. How Can I do this inside the loop that you gave me before?